# Unrecognized Guid format online project error,

Tags: asp.net

I have below code

```
DataTable dg = new System.Data.DataTable(); 
adpa.Fill(dg); 
pac_min = Convert.ToInt32(dg.Rows[0]["Min_Hours"].ToString()); 
package_id = new Guid(dg.Rows[0]["Pakage_id"].ToString()); 
ViewState["packid"] = package_id;
```

And Error :

> Server Error in '/' Application. **Unrecognized Guid format**.
>       Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>       Exception Details: **System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.**
>       Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>       Stack Trace: [FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.] System.GuidResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String
>   failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument, String
>   failureArgumentName, Exception innerException) +2978079
>       System.Guid.TryParseGuid(String g, GuidStyles flags, GuidResult& result) +11140846 System.Guid..ctor(String g) +105
>   admin_airport_view_all_reservation.vehicle_info() +11348
>   admin_airport_view_all_reservation.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs
>   e) +2818
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) +51 System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +772

Comment: Please, add some details; show your code and mark the line where the exception occurs. We can't tell you what's wrong when we see only an exception.

Comment: DataTable dg = new System.Data.DataTable();
                  adpa.Fill(dg);

                  pac_min = Convert.ToInt32(dg.Rows[0]["Min_Hours"].ToString());
                  package_id = new Guid(dg.Rows[0]["Pakage_id"].ToString());

                  ViewState["packid"] = package_id;

Comment: Please, try to debug it and tell me the value of `dg.Rows[0]["Pakage_id"].ToString()`.

Comment: Pakage_id f566f610-b86b-4e49-af5b-f5f05e5e211f    pakage_id data type is uniqueidentifier   in database

Comment: That's pretty strange since it is throwing exception because it cannot parse a GUID. However, it is a proper GUID and it works for me well.

Comment: what should i do now              it's working fine on local host what when run this project  online it gives me this error...